# LXRandR error when (un-)installing software

Tags: 12.04, lxde, lxrandr

I got this error when installing Transmission and uninstalling some unused dependencies in LXDE:

```
/usr/share/menu/lxrandr: missing required tag: "section"
Skipping file because of errors...
```

Is this bad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, [it's just a packaging bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxrandr/+bug/1008678). Somebody [munched](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/lxrandr/trusty/revision/13#debian/menu) the `debian/menu` file and forgot to copy it all over to `lxrandr.menu`.

The [fourth comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxrandr/+bug/1008678/comments/4) gives you a way to fix this with a working menu entry. `sudoedit /usr/share/menu/lxrandr` and fill it with:

```
?package(lxrandr):needs="X11" section="Applications/System/Monitoring"\
  title="LXRandR" longtitle="LXDE monitor configuration tool"\
  description="LXRandR is a GUI application for the Lightweight X11 Desktop Environment (LXDE). It's a very basic monitor config tool utilizing the X extension called RandR to change the screen resolution on the fly."\
  command="/usr/bin/lxrandr"
```